# Don't want to get focus on .goto

Tags: ruby, selenium, webdriver, watir, selenium-chromedriver

How can i let chromium (used by watir) stay in the background?
On every `.goto` the browser is getting the focus and becomes the active window.

Using the same script with ff or ie doesn't act like this.

Best regards.

Example:

```
    require "watir"
    # browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox   # stays in background
    browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome      # getting focus on .goto
    for i in 0..5
      browser.goto "http://google.com?q=#{i}"
      sleep 5
    end
    browser.close
```

Environment:

- windows 7 64bit
- ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16) [i386-mingw32]
- watir (4.0.2 x86-mingw32)
- watir-classic (3.4.0)
- watir-webdriver (0.6.2)
- chromedriver version=26.0.1383.0

Edit: As written in the comments below, i don't want to minimize the window.

Comment: Are you focusing anywhere else whilst running in the background? If you just want to minimize the windows I think I can help you..

Comment: That is the tricky part, the watir-window has to stay open, so that i can watch it and do other thinks in the same time. As i said firefox and ie don't get the focus.

Comment: I get you now. Not the optimal solution but do you think if you do an alt+tab within your loop above will this be sufficient to keep the focus?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve what you are after by using win32ole. The idea is to simulate an ALT + SPACEBAR + N key press so the window will be minimized as soon as it is opened!

That's the simplest I can think of.

Here it is:

```
    require 'win32ole'
skey = WIN32OLE.new('Wscript.Shell')

skey.sendKeys("(%) + (' ') + (n)") #--> minimize window
```

- Note the above has been tested successfully with winXP and Firefox but I cannot see any reason why it shouldn't work with your config as the key combo is windows based.

Best of luck